# C++ Set window below (or above) the icons on the desktop

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to place a window either above or below the icons on the desktop. I mostly just want it to stay attached to the desktop at all times. Similar to Rainmeter or Wallpaper engine. So far, everything I tried either disables interaction, or gets minimized when you use the "Show Desktop" button. Any ideas on how to achieve this? I'm using electron and a native module in node to do this.

Comment: Not sure if it works to prevent automatic minimize, but this should prevent minimize from the application window's button.  `SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE,
               GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_MINIMIZEBOX);` Combine with some [blending](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2005/december/c-at-work-layered-windows-blending-images) and maybe you got it?

Comment: Its actually borderless, so you can't see the minimize button. The Show Desktop shortcut in the bottom-right of the screen still hides it though.

Comment: Think about what you are trying to do. You want your window to continue to hide the desktop, even when Windows' "Show Desktop" button is pressed. Doesn't that strike you as subverting Windows' functionality?

Comment: I'm actually trying to make an interactive desktop replacement, so it's less about subverting, and more about enhancing.

Comment: @Kitsumi A desktop replacement does not go "either above or below the icons on the desktop" because the desktop would have been replaced; there would be no desktop and no icons for this sort of relative placement. *If you are positioning a window, you are not replacing the desktop. You have taken a wrong turn earlier in your design process: see [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old subject, but I'll find out how to do it recently and answer it.

<strike>The method is to find the handle of `SHELLDLL_DefView`, the parent of the desktop window, and then make the `SHELLDLL_DefView` handle the parent of my window to fix it to the desktop.</strike>

The method is to find the handle of `SHELLDLL_DefView`, the owner of the desktop window, and then make the `SHELLDLL_DefView` handle the owner of my window to fix it to the desktop.

`SHELLDLL_DefView` is located under the `Progma` or `WorkerW` handle. This is a code to prevent ShowDesktop from being used in the [Electget](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electget) package created by `ffi-napi` to attach the `Electron` browserWindow to the desktop.

```js
const GWLP_HWNDPARENT = -8;

// find SHELLDLL_DefView in Progma
const progman = user32.FindWindowExA(ref.NULL, ref.NULL, 'Progman', ref.NULL);
let defView = user32.FindWindowExA(progman, ref.NULL, 'SHELLDLL_DefView', ref.NULL ); 

// find SHELLDLL_DefView in WorkerW    
if (!defView) {
  const desktopHWnd = user32.GetDesktopWindow();
  let workerW = 0;
  do {
    workerW = user32.FindWindowExA(desktopHWnd, workerW, 'WorkerW', ref.NULL); 
    defView = user32.FindWindowExA(workerW, ref.NULL, 'SHELLDLL_DefView', ref.NULL );
  } while (!defView && workerW);
}

if (!defView) return false;

// make the SHELLDLL_DefView handle the parent of my window
user32.SetWindowLongPtrA(hWnd, GWLP_HWNDPARENT, defView);
```

This allows you to create a window where you can click and interact without being hidden by ShowDesktop.

---

**2022-03-29**

There was a wrong word, so I corrected it. According to [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/windows-tab-window-properties-dialog-box?view=vs-2022), it is not a parent window, but an owner window. In the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptra#parameters), it is strange that the `GWLP_HWNDPARENT` constant is related to the parent window. However, when tested with `Spy++`, the corresponding constant changes the owner window.